# Google Places API and Measurement of Quota Requests

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I wonder if someone else has experienced the same issue, and might have an answer to it. 
I am using the Google Places API. There I do two kinds of requests

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/
```

and

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/
```

After I have done about 20,000 of these requests my Quota of 150,000 has been eaten up, and I do get an error message.

The strange thing is, when I look at the Google API Console I can see the following: 
In the API & Services Section I can see the following (which reflects the real requests I have done)
[image]

and in the IAM & admin section I do see a much higher value
[image]

This looks artifically high, and is limiting the service way to early. 
Does anyone else have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figuert out, why there is this difference in request in the API view and requests in the Quota view.

When using the TextSeach Places API, each text search request, will be multiplied by a factor 10 towards your free contingent. 
it is mentioned at this page:
[TextSearchRequests](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests)